# change special characters in a string to empty spaces and then get the original string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a function to replace the special characters in asp.net 4.5 and than using this string for the url of my next page.

```
internal static string GetNormalText(string Text)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex("[*'\",_&#^@/]");
    Text = reg.Replace(Text, string.Empty);
    return Text.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower();
}
```

on the next page can i get the original text or is there any way to get the original string back i don't want to use session variable to store the original string as than user can not navigate directly to the url.
e.g My orignal string is `chak 86/6-r` and converted it to `chak-866-r` became the url `http://localhost:58261/chak-866-r/` now on this page can i get this part back or any other solution will be helpfull.

Comment: You can add original string as query parameter.

Comment: adding parameters will be difficult for the user to navigate directly on the page

Comment: actually i want a user friendly url and also i want to get what was the original string so i can get the related data from database and display the results to user

Comment: Then you will need to store somewhere the mapping between user friendly url and original one. Also you need to think about possible collisions in your "friendlifier" algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the original value back is only possible if the transformation itself is unambiguous and reversible. This is not the case here, as if the input is `"I have spaces - and - dashes"`, then the output will be `"I-have-spaces---and---dashes"`, and you have no idea of knowing which were spaces and which were dashes. If the original value contained `*`, `&` etc: they're just *gone*.

Perhaps what you should use here is % url encoding; this has the advantage that it will also work for many more characters (non-ASCII etc), be fully reversible *without* you having to do anything, and still be "friendly" in browsers, but: spaces do not usually get represented as literal spaces in URLs, even in "friendly" mode, because it confuses whether you are doing a search etc. The % encoded version of `chak 86/6-r` is `chak%2086%2F6-r` or `chak+86%2F6-r` (spaces are treated differently).

Alternatively: you can use a synthetic key along with the **non-reversible** slug. This is what Stack Overflow is doing - in your question, the url is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214023/change-special-characters-in-a-string-to-empty-spaces-and-then-get-the-original/` - `62214023` is the synthetic key, and `change-special-characters-in-a-string-to-empty-spaces-and-then-get-the-original` is the display-only, non-reversible slug from your question title. It doesn't matter that we can't reverse it: we can get the original value from the synthetic key.